# Creating TIN in ArcGIS from 5 points using VB.NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, 3d-analyst, vb.net, tin

I am asking this question as I do not have any experience in VB.NET coding. I tried to follow ESRI help but I did not quite understand it. I have 5 points with X,Y and Z dimensions.

How to add these 5 points to make a TIN?

I want VB.NET code.

Comment: There really isn't much point in generating a TIN with five vertices -- If you had 500, or 5000, or 50000 points it would be a different situation.  Learning VB.Net is yet another issue, and not particularly GIS-centric.

Comment: If you know the nodes and elements, you can generate your own TIN definition with LandXML [(see this)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10190/1872), then use the `LandXMLToTin_3d` tool in one of many ways.

Answer (score 3):

The best recommendation I can give is *don't*. Creating a TIN using ArcObjects is a tedious process.

You would be best looking at [IGeoprocessor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002n000000tp000000) and calling the existing tools. If you have 5 points in memory then write them to a [new shape file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005600000004000000.htm) and [create the TIN from points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000001v000000).